# they've got a cheek making you pay

Tags: present-participles

How do you analyze the -ing phrase in the following? What role does it play in the sentence? What does it modify?

> I think they've got a cheek **making you pay to park the car**.

Comment: making doesn't modify a cheek. It seems to be a participial construction.

Comment: Do you mean, "... they've got cheek..." (no "a")? with "a cheek" it's not proper English

Comment: @gotube That is from an Oxford dictionary.

Comment: @Apollyon Can you link the source? I suppose it might be U.K. English, but it's wrong here in Canada. Anyway, do your question, does it clarify anything to change the sentence to, "They've got *some nerve* making you pay to park the car." If not, then the answer is as bak1936 said above.

Comment: It's listed as British English, and I think it means "nerve" as you said. But calling the fragment "a participial construction" is too broad as the latter has various functions.

Comment: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/cheek_1?q=cheek

Comment: @gotube you are right, it is predominantly a British English expression.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+got+a+cheek%3A+eng_us_2019%2Chave+got+a+cheek%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20got%20a%20cheek%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20got%20a%20cheek%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Apollyon It is a perfectly normal participial phrase. https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html

Comment: Could you describe what role it serves in my particular sentence?

Comment: @Apollyon The word "cheek" in this context means a disrespectful attitude, such as a schoolchild telling a teacher that he is wrong. "Has got a cheek" or "giving cheek", or "being cheeky" are all ways of saying this. The teacher's response might be "Stop being cheeky", or (more colloquially) "enough of your cheek".

Comment: It's easier to understand if you put a comma in: "I think they've got a cheek, making you pay to park the car". The first clause says that "they" are being disrespectful, the second clause states what act the speaker considers disrespectful. Consider "He was very rude, calling you that name".

Comment: And, FWIW, in the Americas, "cheek" with this meaning is an uncountable noun

Answer (score 1):

I agree with JavaLatte that the words in bold constitute a participle clause.

As it says [here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/participle-clauses) "We can use participle clauses when the participle and the verb in the main clause have the same subject." In your sentence the participle is 'making'. The verb in the main clause is 'have'. The subject of both is 'people.' I think it's similar to "I bit my nails waiting for them to get home."

Such clauses usually allow us to use fewer words. Your sentence might otherwise be, "they've got a cheek when they make you..."

The sentence means, "I think the people who insisted you pay to park the car are brazen/impertinent/impudent".
"[Someone's] got a cheek" is  an everyday expression in the UK and, as gotube says, it's equivalent to "They've got a[UK]/some[Canada] [nerve](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nerve)" (definition 2.1).

Comment: Is it correct to say, "Making you pay to park the car, they've got a cheek"?

Comment: @Apollyon It's not colloquial English. Although if you put more emphasis in it sounds better:  "Making you pay to park the car!  They've got a cheek!"

Comment: @Apollyon With many such sentences it IS OK to swap the two halves: "Waiting for them I bit my nails" for example. But as Paul Johnson says, that particular re-arrangement isn't colloquial. (Except, perhaps, with his suggested layout.) I agree it SHOULD be. But it isn't!

Comment: The impossibility of swapping the two halves suggests to me that a different analysis from that of "I bit my nails waiting for them" is necessary. A more similar example would be "He got a job washing cars" (*Washing cars, he got a job" is impossible on the reading associated with the unfronted version.)

Comment: @Apollyon Swapping the two halves of the 'cheek' sentence  is _not_ an 'impossibility'. The result is just less colloquial.

Comment: Could you find attested examples of such fronted "cheek" sentences? Some people might say a particular imagined sentence is possible just because it fits their analysis. But without actual supportive examples, the analysis and that imagined sentence are still questionable.

Comment: @Appolyon, Fronting a participle phrase gives a literary feel to a sentence (Oxford Guide to English Grammar 139.4.a): this is not compatible with an informal idiom like "they've got a cheek".  Fronting is perfectly grammatical in this sentence, but it is not idiomatic.